# Flexbox - Display list vertically instead of wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple flexbox list like this...

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
  
}

li {
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
  <li>List Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

When there is not enough room for the list to be displayed horizontally then I would like it to display vertically.

Is there a way in flexbox to tell it to display vertically instead of wrap when there is not enough space?

Comment: what do you mean enough room? how many box do you want per row(max box before set full width)?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use media queries alongside with flex direction property.

change the flex direction of the ul tag with a media query

```
ul {
   display: flex;
   @media (max-width: <Xpx>){
     flex-direction: column
   }
}
```

Xpx - The position  you want to  stack it vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Use this trick

```
ul li:nth-last-child(n+6):first-child,
ul li:nth-last-child(n+6):first-child ~ *{
  // set new style in case you have 5 li or more
}
```

Working code

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  list-style:none;
  }
ul li:nth-last-child(n+6):first-child,
ul li:nth-last-child(n+6):first-child ~ *{
    flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
  <li>List Item 5</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
  <li>List Item 5</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
  <li>List Item 5</li>
</ul>

<h1>Same style with 5 items or less</h1>
<ul>
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
  <li>List Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media-queries to set different properties at a different width, 
and play a game at `https://flexboxfroggy.com/` to master flexbox.

To generate a media query for a specific screen resolution visit

```
http://giona.net/tools/css3-mediaquery-generator/
```

Hope this helps